# What LED PWM controller has marking AT508CS?

Tags: led, pwm, identification, surface-mount

I have an LED worklight with low- and strobe-functions.

One click: On - full Power
Two clicks: half Power
Three clicks: strobe
Four clicks: Off

The controller is circled:

[image]

No markings on the top so I desoldered it and found the markings on the bottom.

[image]

AT508CS (might be AT50BCS, but I don't Think so)
RBFKG1000
1904 X

Tried to identify the pinout:
[image]

Comment: I can't find anything that fits the bill, but that may be a small 8 bit microcontroller. What is the pinout of that chip?(based on the traces on the board)

Comment: Hi. I tried to identify the pinout. The one that says "Signal out" is where the signal comes out from the chip. If i short the ones that says "Switch" if switches mode to the next. "In" is simply the in-pin.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that it is simply a microcontroller. Anything that would implement modes like that would have to be an ASIC of some sort if it weren't a microcontroller. Then again, I see Chinese letters on the board,  that along with the lettering on the bottom side of the component which I have never seen before could mean an ASIC that you can't buy off the shelf, designed and manufactured in mass just for this purpose

Comment: Why do you need a chip that implements that functionality? If you want to create duplicates it might be worth your time to use any SOIC-8 microcontroller and program it to do that

Comment: Thanks c10yas, I Think I'll do just that. It's completly new to me so it'll be fun learing how to do it :)

Comment: You can get pretty cheap ATTiny85 microcontrollers in DIP8 packages that you can prototype with on a breadboard before designing your own PCB. STM8s can be found in tiny 8 pin packages as well. Or if you want to go really small, I believe microchip makes sot-23-6 8bit microcontrollers that would serve this purpose as well

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a one-time programmable microcontroller pic12c508